# Is there any ActiveMQ Performance PoC?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

Is there any PoC to prove that ActiveMQ has good perfomance, vertically (speed) and horizontally (scalability)? Either with or without Spring JMS?

Because I see that it cannot process small messages in more than 50 transaction/sec. When I use Spring JMS, the consumer is raised only slowly (I set maxConcurrentConsumers > concurrentConsumers)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of details to consider. You have 50 msg/sec of what? Persistent messages? Non persistent? Are you using queues? durable subscribers on topics? Are you using selectors? Request/reply? Transactions? Where is your bottle neck? The broker itself? The consumer? The producer? A performance benchmark would not make much sense to look at unless you look at a benchmark of a very specific scenario.

Red Ben Odays [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463415/activemq-performance-gotchas-and-precautions) on this question for some input on tweaking the broker itself.

Another note, when using Spring JMS, be aware that it was designed to be easy to use with default settings while it requires some work if you want push the performance. Some info [at AMQ website](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html) and in [this blog post](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.se/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html) by Bruce Snyder.

You can make your own benchmark report with your specific criterias/hardware/setup using the [included benchmark test](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html) in ActiveMQ. It will much more valid than any old report found on the Internet.

Comment: I did try Bruce's suggestions, but the result is still below my expectation (50 msg/sec of persistent message with queue without selectors, non embedded broker). The message consumption is still slow. And.. The included benchmark test doesn't give me clear information about how to analyze the result.

Comment: If you went though those suggestions in my post from increasing broker memory limit to tuning the JMS template and JMS consumer for caching - then so be it. It might be that you cannot get better throughput in your scenario. While ActiveMQ gives you a decent mix of performance and a very flexible broker, RabbitMQ might outperformance it in raw processing power - but in the end, ZeroMQ outperforms RabbitMQ and raw UDP datagrams outperforms ZeroMQ, so there is always a trade.